# creating object from multiple array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping through an object that contains multiple telephone numbers as keys and arrays with objects as values.

I have written a reduce method that groups all of the schedules together, except for one issue.

if you run the snippet you see that `res` is:
`{trackingNumber: [ [Array] ]}`

I need the object to look like:
`{trackingNumber: [Array]}`

The issue I continue to run into is trying to pop or slice or do anything by initial index makes the first array that is concatted (Object.values(res)) basically it enumerates the first object of that array as the first 7 elements of the value associated with tracking number.

{trackingNumber: [0:string, 1:string, 2:string, 3: {object of strings in 0 1 and 2}]}

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let todayNewTollFree = [
{paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},],
tracking: "+18003160182"},
{paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},],
tracking: "+18003160182"
},
{
paymentSchedule: [],
tracking: "+12134105385"
},
{
paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},],
tracking: "+18007084605"
},
{
paymentSchedule:[{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},],
tracking: "+18007100629"
}
]

let test = todayNewTollFree.reduce(function (res, obj) {
    let key = obj.tracking;

    if (res[key]) {
      res[key] = res[key].map((key) =>
        [key].flat().concat(obj.paymentSchedule)
      );
    } else res[key] = [obj.paymentSchedule];
    for (const tracking in res) {
      let values = Object.values(res[key]).flat();

      console.log(tracking);
      console.log(values);
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
      
      console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The `for in` loop creates a flat array correctly but every attempt I have to go back and call or assign tracking to the newly created array isn't working.

Comment: Hard to help when data posted is abstract and can't be used to test your code with. Try to generate a simplified minimal set that has enough properties to actually make this run. Then from that minimalist set provide better example of expected results. To be honest it's not clear what's different from your current output and expected output. Note you can click on `<>` in question editor and create a runnable stack snippet that logs right into this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a new key to the object, you should not place it inside an array literal `[...]` (as that creates an array whose first element is an array) and should simply assign the array itself to the property. Furthermore, when adding to an array, `Array#map` is not necessary and `Array#concat` will do the job.

```js
let todayNewTollFree = [ {paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},], tracking: "+18003160182"}, {paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},], tracking: "+18003160182" }, { paymentSchedule: [], tracking: "+12134105385" }, { paymentSchedule: [{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},], tracking: "+18007084605" }, { paymentSchedule:[{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},{amount:500},], tracking: "+18007100629" } ]
let test = todayNewTollFree.reduce(function (res, obj) {
  let key = obj.tracking;
  if (res[key]) {
    res[key] = res[key].concat(obj.paymentSchedule)
  } else res[key] = obj.paymentSchedule;
  return res;
}, {});
console.log(test)
```

Comment: im like shook. cause i swear to flip flopping something or other ive tried something so close to this 1000 times.

Comment: sorry i had to walk away for second yes!